# HttpClient get Timeout exceptions from WCF service when request size increase

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, certificate, httpclient

I am trying to communicate with a WCF SOAP service from my .net6 apllication using **HttpClient** (I made sure the content wrap up inside an envelope and I set the header content type to be application/soap+xml):

```
var client =_httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
var response = await client.PostAsync(_uri, new StringContent(message.Body, Encoding.UTF8, mediaType: "application/soap+xml"));
```

also the server has a certificate configure like that:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MyHttpsBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" sendTimeout="00:03:20">
      <security mode="Transport" >
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
      </security>
    </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

Evrerything works fine but as soon as the request body size increase (just 37k though) I am starting to get timeout exceptions on the client, I also have another client that use the [**ClientBase**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.clientbase-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) class and there everything works.

If I am turning off the certificate mention above I don't get any timeout exception also.

Comment: "increase" what sort of size are we talking? Please also show relevant code where you send the request

Comment: You can do the cleanup in the finally block of try/finally, or if you do the cleanup by calling the Dispose method of the IDisposable object, use the using block.